# How to read text from pop up kind of window having class type " x-window x-resizable-pinned"

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

How to read text from pop up kind of window having class type " x-window x-resizable-pinned".

Website Link: https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html?id=allAnnouncements

Once opened click on any link under the column subject I want to read the fields in the pop up like Symbol, Company, Industry and then close the popup.

This is actually niether a popup nor a window. This content is within the same iframe. I tried all the locators (including xpath which works in similar situations) but none of them are working.

This looks like java script display. how can we handle this situations?

[image]

Comment: I'm programming in Java. I tried locators like Id, ClassName, XPath but its not locating the elements.

Comment: Could you share here your tried code here??

Comment: WebElement symbolname=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));


System.out.println(symbolname.getText());

Comment: WebElement closebutton=driver.findElement(By.className("x-tool x-tool-close "));
closebutton.click();

Comment: When you tried this code what was the result?? Is there any exception or anything else??

Comment: And are you sure your locator is correct??

Comment: Actually `className` does not support compound class you should try as `WebElement closebutton=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".x-tool.x-tool-close")); closebutton.click();` and let me know..

Comment: Could you share popup HTML here??

Comment: Tried cssSelector but getting the same error. The error is org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

Comment: Open browser console by pressing f12 and execute this `document.querySelector(".x-tool.x-tool-close")` and let me know is it locate correct element or not??

Comment: And as you are saying this element is inside an iframe so did you switched that iframe before finding element as `driver.switchTo().frame("frame name or id")`..??

Comment: Finalllyyyyy Im able to execute.. If you see the class name "x-tool x-tool-close", it has two names inside it, one parent and other child. I tried using just child name and it worked.                                                   

WebElement closebutton=driver.findElement(By.className("x-tool-close"));

Comment: Good you have got it..:)

Comment: All the content is in single iframe including this popup.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt response..!!

Comment: No problem, you can post it as an answer and later accept it which helps to other as well.. Thanks..:)